# DropdownListFor - Null Reference Exception on page model

Tags: entity-framework-ctp5

I'm trying to save one of my Models to the database.  Given the models:

```
public class Foo {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public virtual Bar Something { get; set; }
}

public class Bar {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class FooPageModel {
    public Foo F { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Bars { get; set; }
}
```

In my controller I have:

```
public ActionResult Add(){
     var bars = ... // get all bars from db context
     var barsList = new List<SelectListItem>();
     barsList.AddRange(bars.Select(b => new SelectListItem {
          Text = b.Name,
          Value = b.Name
     }));

     var model = new FooPageModel
     {
          Bars = barsList
     };
     return View("Add", model);
 }
```

Now for the View (strongly typed to FooPageModel):

```
<%: Html.DropdownListFor(f => f.F.Bar, Model.Bars) %>
```

The view renders fine, with the values I expect, but when I submit the page form, I get a NullReferenceException (on the view line pasted above before the action on the controller is ever reached).  I thought maybe if I modified my controller code to:

```
var model = new FooPageModel
{
     F = new Foo(),
     Bars = barsList
}
```

However, this fails as well.  I suppose I could re-write FooPageModel to just be a list of strings of the information I want, but it seems redundant to duplicate Model logic; I'm pretty new to CTP in general, so maybe that's how it's done?

I was able to code up something similar for a ComplexType (an address Model) and had no problems.  If the stack trace would be helpful, let me know and I'll post it.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solved:  It's my fault for only putting psuedo code up and not the actual code.  The problem was that in my model, I had a couple of int and float objects.  These are created in the database as non-nullable types.  I changed my model to use int? and float? and everything seems to be ok.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't showing the code where you return the `ActionResult`, but you need to make sure you are passing the model to the view, like this:

```
public ActionResult Add() {
    ...

    return View(model);  // send the model to the view
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't include returning the model in the Controller (I just edited to show that).  But clearly that wasn't the problem, as I only get the null exception on the form post and not on page load.